# How does serialization work behind the scenes?

Tags: c#, .net, serialization

I would like to know more about how serialization works in .NET (or Java) behind the scenes, particularly how the attributes make the classes/properties/fields serializable. AFAIK, the attributes, for example [Seraliable], in C# are nothing but classes that store metadata. They do not add anything to the source code. However, by adding a few attributes in a certain way, classes can be serialized and deserialized without a fuss. This seems to be quite magical to me. Does the compiler use these attributes to add code? Or does the runtime environment use these attributes to get and send information? My guess is that the runtime environment use the reflectors to get access to these attributes and then use these attributes to get or send information, but I need confirmation, further explanation and references on this.

Please note that my question is not about how to use serialization. This question is specific about how the .NET framework handles serialization behind the scenes.

Any help is welcomed. Thank you in advance.

Comment: you should search for it and here you can ask question specific to programing problem if you are facing some problem in your code....

Comment: Discussion posts are not welcome on SO. I'm afraid there is not much you can do to make this post appropriately scoped for SO.

Comment: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Xml/System/Xml/Serialization/XmlSerializer.cs,292c7197dcb706a1

Comment: Hi @JLRishe Thanks, the link helps.

Comment: this missing piece is a thing called "Reflection" which allows you to query objects, find out what types they are, what properties they have, what attributes they have, invoke those attributes

Comment: This question is too general for Stack Overflow.  There are numerous libraries in .NET which perform serialization i.e. convert objects to and from a string representation.  You should ask a specific question about a specific serializer. As JLRishe suggested for many of these you can examine the source code.